# Discord.py check if argument is is a number between certain values

Tags: python, discord.py

We have a very simple discord script where a user will type !dino 1234

And the script will return a http://www.url.com/images/1234.png

Being new to python and discord.py i can't work out how to make a check that the argument entered is between 1-100 (the number of pictures) and only to return the url if so.

So if arg > 0 &  <101

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.command(name='dino')
async def dino(ctx,arg :int):
 
   await ctx.send('http://www.url.com/images/{}.png'.format(arg))  
   await ctx.send('Picture #{}'.format(arg))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.command(name='dino')
async def dino(ctx, arg):
   try:
      if int(arg) > 0 and int(arg) < 101:
         await ctx.send('http://www.url.com/images/{}.png'.format(arg))  
         await ctx.send('Picture #{}'.format(arg))
   except:
      await ctx.send('Please enter a valid number between 1 and 100')
```

Comment: This is still allowing the bot to post any number. But thanks

Comment: @LegionOfBrad Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant. I have updated the answer, see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.command(name='dino')
async def dino(ctx, arg:int):
    if 0 <= arg <= 100: #This will check the number is between 0 and 100.
        await ctx.send('http://www.url.com/images/{}.png'.format(arg))  
        await ctx.send('Picture #{}'.format(arg))
```